# Running datomic starter pro in docker , cannot create a database with peer on localhost

Tags: docker, datomic

I am running datomic pro starter in a docker container like this:

```
PS C:\server\dockers\datomic-pro-transactor> docker run --rm -p 4334-4336:4334-4336 myimage
Launching with Java options -server -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50
Starting datomic:dev://localhost:4334/<DB-NAME>, storing data in: data ...
System started datomic:dev://localhost:4334/<DB-NAME>, storing data in: data
```

The transactor config is like this:

```
protocol=dev
host=localhost
port=4334
```

Then i try to create a database as per the documentation from my hostmachine (not in docker):

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])
(def db-uri "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/hello")
(d/create-database db-uri)
```

And it fails with this:

```
PS C:\server\datomic> bin\repl
C:\server\datomic>setlocal
C:\server\datomic>call bin\classpath
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (require '[datomic.api :as d])
nil
user=> (def db-uri "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/hello")
#'user/db-uri
user=> (d/create-database db-uri)
Execution error (ActiveMQNotConnectedException) at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl/createSessionFactory (ServerLocatorImpl.java:787).
AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
user=>
```

I can telnet to all three ports on the container , so there seems to be ok connection.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may wish to try the Datomic users mailing list:  datomic@googlegroups.com

Comment: Or the slack channel:   https://app.slack.com/client/T03RZGPFR/C03RZMDSH

Answer (score 0):

> (def db-uri "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/hello")

Here you're trying to connect your Peer application to the transactor, but you should be trying to connect your application to the DB instead. For example, if your DB is running on Port 3000 you should use this uri:

> (def db-uri "datomic:dev://localhost:8000/hello")